# Assigning values to correlative series in r

Tags: r, series

I hope you can help me with this issue I have.
I have a big dataframe, to simplify it, it look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(radius = c (2,3,5,7,4,6,9,8,3,7,8,9,2,4,5,2,6,7,8,9,1,10,8))
df$num <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,12,13,1,14,15,16,17,18,19,1,1)
df
```

The column $num has correlative series (1-11, 1, 12-13, 1, 14-19,1,1)
I would like to assign a value (sorted) per each correlative serie as a column. the outcome should be like this:

```
df$outcome <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7)
df
```

thanks a lot!

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the difference between adjacent elements in 'num' using `diff` and check whether it is not equal to 1.  The logical output will be one less than the length of the 'num' vector.  We pad with 'TRUE' and `cumsum` to get the expected output.

```
df$outcome <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(df$num)!=1))
df$outcome
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty efficient!